# Android/Facebook API get member since

Tags: java, android

I am trying to figure out how could I get the exact date I  registered on my facebook.

I am using this code to get datas from facebook(using JSON) but I cant figure out how to get the member since

```
 JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
 ////////
 String ID = profile.getString("id");
```

Is there any way I could do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer:
The Facebook API, Graph API and FQL, does not have that provision. That being said, the Facebook website (user, not developer) does not provide that information to the account holder either.

There may or may not be a reason for Facebook to not reveal that information. A search on SO gave this link: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8821957/450534. Although, the platform in question for this question is `python`, the available API options, essentially, remain common across platforms.